# Matlab find min/max of function

Tags: matlab, function, max, min

I'm trying to write an M-file that finds the max/min of a function, given a certain range.

Let's say I have defined an equation in the command window like so:

```
> y = @(x) -1*x^2 + 3
y =

  function_handle with value:

    @(x)-1*x^2+3
```

And let's say my desired range is from -3 to 3... So I would start my M-file with

```
function fminmax = input(f, lowerbound, upperbound)
```

but then what would I use? I've been googling for a while and I cant find anything helpful. Please help!

Comment: [This](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html) was the first hit when I googled your question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the already existing function `x = fminbnd(fun, x1, x2)` which gives you the min for a function handle `fun` in the range of `x1` and `x2`. To get the max you could just use the negative of your function handle.

Your function could look like this:

```
function [min, max] = fminmax(f, lowerbound, upperbound)
    min = fminbnd(f, lowerbound, upperbound);
    max = fminbnd(@(x) -f(x), lowerbound, upperbound);
end
```

Comment: Matlab spits out an error message when I try this. It says "Undefined operator '*' for input arguments of type 'function_handle' "

Comment: @Marcus my bad. A function handle is no numeric value and therefore can't be multiplied with **-1**. I edited my answer. This should do the trick.